# How do I figure out what policy I need to add from a 403 response?

Tags: hcl, vault, hashicorp

I send a HTTP request to my Hashicorp Vault instance and receive a 403 HTTP response.
How do I reverse engineer the policy I need to add from my request path?

```
curl \
-v \
-H "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" \
https://myvault/v1/sys/plugins/catalog

< HTTP/2 403 
< date: Tue, 18 May 2021 20:52:52 GMT
< content-type: application/json
< content-length: 60
< cache-control: no-store
< strict-transport-security: max-age=15724800; includeSubDomains
< 
{"errors":["1 error occurred:\n\t* permission denied\n\n"]}
```

Answer (score 0):

The **Hashicorp vault** does not suggest or show any error which permission is missing.
Instead, you can have a more generic and even it's easy most of the time to set the permission if you look at the pattern or the way it's set.

In your case, I can see you are trying to perform a `GET` request to the path `/sys/plugins/catalog` and is getting 403.

so, you can have in the policy like this

```
path "sys/plugins/catalog" {
  capabilities = ["read"]
}
```

The `GET` request is of the capability type `read`, you can read more about these [here.](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/policies#capabilities)

more on the [documentation](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/system/plugins-catalog#list-plugins) .

**TL;DR**

The request you make, set it in the path.
The method you trigger sets the equivalent [capabilities](https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/concepts/policies#capabilities).
all would go in the policy.
Use wildcard in the path and wherever you need(Just in case).